# Forder address with WWW inside of a directory?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have a website located within `DEV` folder. But a snipped that I have an access to will not force address to be redirected to WWW....

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  ^example.com/dev/ [nocase]
RewriteRule ^(.*)         http://www.example.com/dev/$1 [last,redirect=301]
```

How to do this properly? Assuming that I am placing the HTACCESS inside of that directory.

My code redirects me to `www.example.com`, instead `www.example.com/dev/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the HTTP_HOST variable is *only the hostname*, it doesn't contain any path information. So try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^dev/(.*)$ http://www.example.com/dev/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: This keep redirecting me to www.example.com as well. =/

Comment: Correction, if I type 'example.com/dev/' it takes me to 'www.example.com'. But when I type 'example.com/dev/index.php' it doesn't add WWW in front.

Comment: @HelpNeeder then something else is doing that redirecting, because the rule doesn't do anything like that.

Comment: Could HTACCESS from the main '/' directory rewrite HTACCESS from '/dev/' directory?

Comment: @HelpNeeder no, subdirectories always have precedence over parent directories.

Comment: I will ask server admin for this. Nothing on my development page does this. Seems like this is the answer, though something else might obscure my result. Thanks.